# Any bad consequences if LAN IP of Windows machine is fixed?

Tags: windows, ip, lan, connection, network-adapter

I'm setting fixed LAN IP for my Windows machine with:

```
IP: 192.168.1.102 (Current one)
Mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.1.1
```

My Windows computer is turned off every day, **what may happen if the IP .102 above has already been assigned to another computer in my house**, for example, tablet or phone.

Are there any conflicts? or my Windows computer fails to connect to the Internet? I need the fixed IP to connect to host from a Docker container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An IP address can only belong to one system at a time, so yes, if your DHCP server allocates it to another device you will have difficulties reaching the Internet.  The solution is to put the machines with static IP address inside the same subnet but outside of the range IP addresses are allocated from (this can typically be viewed and changed in the router). Typically the first and last few addresses in a range are not given to DHCP.

An alternative is to statically assign IPs in the DHCP server.

Note that you mat not immediately have a problem with address assignments in the scenario you posit as many/most DHCP servers keep a record of IP addresses associated with MAC addresses and try to keep the assignments from changing so as not to break active sessions.